# How to pass a texture to a vertex shader? (iOS & Metal) (IOAF code 5)

Tags: ios, textures, metal, vertex-shader

I want to modify a geo grid with a texture in vertex shader.

I've got a working Metal pipeline.

I pass the `MTLTexture` in like this:

```
commandEncoder.setVertexTexture(texture, index: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexSamplerState(sampler, index: 0)
```

My vertex shader func:

```
vertex VertexOut distort3DVTX(const device VertexIn* vertecies [[ buffer(0) ]],
                              unsigned int vid [[ vertex_id ]],
                              texture2d<float> inTex [[ texture(0) ]],
                              sampler s [[ sampler(0) ]]) {
    
    VertexIn vtxIn = vertecies[vid];
    float x = vtxIn.position[0];
    float y = vtxIn.position[1];

    float u = x / 2 + 0.5;
    float v = y / 2 + 0.5;
    float2 uv = float2(u, v);
    float4 c = inTex.sample(s, uv);
    
    VertexOut vtxOut;
    vtxOut.position = float4(x + (c.r - 0.5), y + (c.g - 0.5), 0, 1);
    vtxOut.texCoord = vtxIn.texCoord;
    
    return vtxOut;
}
```

This is the error I see:

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)

If I replace `float4 c = inTex.sample(s, uv);` with `float4 c = 0.5;` I don't see the error. So it's definitely something with sampling the texture...

Any idea how to solve `IOAF code 5`?

**Update 1:**

The error code dose not seem to be related to the texture, the same thing happens when I try to pass a uniform buffer...

```
const device Uniforms& in [[ buffer(1) ]]
```

**Update 2:**

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> GPU Frame Capture -> Metal

Previously I had it set to `Automatically Enabled`.

Now I get relevant error logs:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
>
> validateFunctionArguments:3469: failed assertion `Vertex Function(particle3DVTX): missing buffer binding at index 1 for in[0].'

Tho I'm crashing before I `drawPrimitives` or `endEncoding`...

**Update 3:**

Here's how I pass the uniform values:

```
var vertexUnifroms: [Float] = ...
let size = MemoryLayout<Float>.size * vertexUnifroms.count
guard let uniformsBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(length: size, options: []) else {
    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    throw RenderError.uniformsBuffer
}
let bufferPointer = uniformsBuffer.contents()
memcpy(bufferPointer, &vertexUnifroms, size)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(uniformsBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
```

**Update 4:**

Clean helped. I now see where it's crashing; `drawPrimitives`. My `vertexUnifroms` was empty, fixed the bug, and now I've got uniforms!

Comment: Are you running with Metal validation enabled? If that doesn't help identify the issue, have you tried powering you Mac down for 10 minutes, rebooting, and retrying? Does it happen on other Macs?

Comment: @KenThomases I've got Metal validation enabled. I'm running on iPhone. Not sure what's causing the crash...

Comment: Oh, right. You tagged it [ios]. :) Um, then, have you rebooted the phone?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running, and on which type of device?

Comment: I'll try a reboot, have't actually rebooted in a while..
I ran the test on iOS 12.0 beta, will try iOS 12.1. I'm on a iPhone X.

Comment: @KenThomases Same thing after reboot and iOS 12.1, tho updated some progress in the post with `GPU Frame Capture` -> `Metal`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I discovered that I needed to set Vertex Buffer Bytes with:

```
commandEncoder.setVertexBytes(&vertexUniforms, length: MemoryLayout<VertexUniforms>.size, index: 1)
```

...the same thing can also be done for the Fragment Buffer Bytes:

```
commandEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&fragmentUniforms, length: MemoryLayout<FragmentUniforms>.size, index: 1)
```